# Javascript to Find Invoice No. with a given prefix

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `div` tag that has a very long list of invoices.

Each invoice starts with the word "Invoice No.:" and has the identifying number after it like "Invoice No.: 1", "Invoice No.: 2" etc and so on.

Here's what I've got soo far:

```html
Invoice No.:
<input type="number" name="Search" autocomplete="off">
<input type="button" id="Search" value="Find" onclick="search();">

<div id="Invoice">
  <p>Invoice No.: 1<br> Amount: 300</p>

  <p>Invoice No.: 2<br> Amount: 1978</p>

  <p>Invoice No.: 3<br> Amount: 700</p>
</div>

<script>
  function search() {
    var str = "";
    var n = str.startsWith("Invoice No.: ");
    document.getElementById("Invoice").innerHTML = n;
  }
</script>
```

I want to create a javascript/jquery search form that accepts only number input and then prefixes the word "Invoice No.:" in it on hitting the search button and on search jump to that word and highlights the result.

Comment: i did it before you deleted the last post :( let me do it again

Comment: What is your question and/or specific problem? Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz sorry about that, the question was getting too many downvotes for not having a code of my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.querySelectorAll` to select all the p tag. Then use `indexOf` to check if `innerHTML` have the required invoice number.Using `setAttribute` set `tabIndex` to `focus` the element

```js
var getAllElement = document.querySelectorAll("#Invoice p")

function search() {
  var str = "";
  //var n = str.startsWith("Invoice No.: ");
  var srchVal = "Invoice No.: " + document.getElementById("num").value;
  getAllElement.forEach(function(item) {
    if (item.innerHTML.indexOf(srchVal) > -1) {
      item.classList.add('highlight');
      item.setAttribute('tabIndex', 1)
      item.focus()

    } else {
      item.removeAttribute('tabIndex');
      item.classList.remove('highlight')
    }
  })
}
```

```css
.highlight {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
Invoice No.: <input type="number" id="num" name="Search" autocomplete="off"> <input type="button" id="Search" value="Find" onclick="search();">

<div id="Invoice">
  <p>Invoice No.: 1<br> Amount: 300</p>

  <p>Invoice No.: 2<br> Amount: 1978</p>

  <p>Invoice No.: 3<br> Amount: 700</p>
  <p>Invoice No.: 4<br> Amount: 300</p>

  <p>Invoice No.: 5<br> Amount: 1978</p>

  <p>Invoice No.: 6<br> Amount: 700</p>
  <p>Invoice No.: 7<br> Amount: 300</p>

  <p>Invoice No.: 8<br> Amount: 1978</p>

  <p>Invoice No.: 9<br> Amount: 700</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Suppose there is no <p> tag and the invoice content is in plain text, how can I highlight the same?

Comment: But your question have p tag.Now it is not good to change the problem statement

Comment: @CodyCodes If there is no `p` tag then you need to search for the text inside parent `div`.Then wrap it with a html element so that class can be added and focus can be set.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function search() {
    var invoice = document.getElementById('invoice'+document.getElementById('numbertext').value)
    var arr_elms = document.body.getElementsByTagName("P");
    for (var i = 0; i < arr_elms.length; i++) {
      if(arr_elms[i].getAttribute("invoice") != null){  
        arr_elms[i].classList.remove('focus');
      }
    }
    if (invoice){
      invoice.classList.add('focus');
    }
    location.href = '#invoice'+document.getElementById('numbertext').value
}
```

```css
.focus{
  background-color: red;
  color : white;
}
```

```html
Invoice No.: <input type="number" name="Search" autocomplete="off" id="numbertext"> <input type="button" id="Search" value="Find" onclick="search();">

<div id="Invoice">
<p id="invoice1" invoice>Invoice No.: 1<br>
Amount: 300</p>

<p id="invoice2" invoice>Invoice No.: 2<br>
Amount: 1978</p>

<p id="invoice3" invoice>Invoice No.: 3<br>
Amount: 700</p>

<p id="invoice4" invoice>Invoice No.: 4<br>
Amount: 700</p>

<p id="invoice5" invoice>Invoice No.: 5<br>
Amount: 700</p>

<p id="invoice6" invoice>Invoice No.: 6<br>
Amount: 700</p>

<p id="invoice7" invoice>Invoice No.: 7<br>
Amount: 700</p>

<p id="invoice8" invoice>Invoice No.: 8<br>
Amount: 700</p>

<p id="invoice9" invoice>Invoice No.: 9<br>
Amount: 700</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `jQuery`, you can loop through all `p` elements and use `indexOf` to match the elements ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ymdnwfae/)):

```
function searchParagraphOfInvoiceNo(number)
{
    var search = 'Invoice No.: ' + number,
            match = null;
    $('#Invoice p').each(function() {
        if ($(this).text().indexOf(search) >= 0) {
              match = $(this);
            return false;
        }
    });
    return match;
}

function focusParagraph(p)
{
    if (!p || p.length == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: p.offset().top + 'px'
    }, 'fast');
}

var p = searchParagraphOfInvoiceNo(9);
if (p) {
    focusParagraph(p);
} else {
    alert('Not found');
}
```